# Different colors, same code

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, colors

My friend and I decided to start making a little game to learn openGL. We are using Eclipse Saros to make this happen. We quickly ran into problems. Colours would not display correctly on my monitor. We're running exactly the same code, but the result is different.

Sloppy colour testing code:

```
public void render() {
GL11.glColor3f((float) (255 / 255.0), (float) (165 / 255.0), (float) (0 / 255.0));
Graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
}
```

Using a program that we both downloaded, which lets you get the Hex code of a given pixel on the screen, we found out that his program displayed the correct colour (#FFA500), but mine didn't (#FFD200).

Comment: maybe your graphic card settings are manipulating the final result. did you change any settings that could cause this?

Comment: And if you run your program on his computer and vice versa? Also, what about other colours? And I couldn't help but notice that 0xD2 is 0xA5 with the lower 7 bits flipped, but that could be a coincidence.

Comment: @Moh-AW We haven't changed anything ourselves. We both run nvidia cards, though his is a laptop, could that influnce anything?

Comment: @MrLister We're using the Saros plugin for Eclipse, so we're editing and running the same code. It's basically live coding within a proper IDE.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for this. It depends what your program is measuring:

**1.** The color of the pixel that is assigned to it by the system

**2.** The color of the pixel that is displayed by your monitor

For case 1, both colors should be the same.

For case 2, you monitors calibration is maybe not accurate.

3rd possible reason: One of you is measuring 1st case, the other one is measuring 2nd case. And this is where you error comes from.

Comment: This is the program that we're using [link]http://sourceforge.net/projects/colorsfinder/?source=recommended, as far as we know it should be measuring the color it's assigned by the system. Do you know any programs that measure the system assigned colour for sure?

Comment: I think there are various browser tools which achieve this as well. just google it

Comment: I checked with another tool as well. It sure seems like the colour assigned is #FFD200.

Comment: strange. but I have no more idea